# jboss-eap-7.1 ssl certificate expired

Tags: jboss, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, truststore

I am new to the jboss world. I have a web service where I have the following configuration in my standalone.xlm file:

```
<security-realm name="MyRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="serverksfile.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password1" alias="mykey" key-password="password2"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <truststore path="clientksfile.truststore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password1"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
```

And I have a question, the certificate contained serverksfile.keystore is expired but my web services works correctly. I am using Postman for testing, any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Postman settings, check the option that avoids Certificate Validation. Only use that in non-prod enviroments.

Settings -- General -- SSL certificate verification, and turn off.